# Get Google Drive apps script onItemsSelectedTrigger to execute every time a file is selected

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Google Drive onItemsSelectedTrigger only executes once for each file selected and displays a cached response the second and subsequent times the file is selected, have to change folder or refresh UI for it to execute again. Want a solution to have it execute every time a file is selected (need to check file version against external system to guide users).

Running this example and continuously clicking two different files, the execution logs shows onItemsSelectedTrigger only executes twice, the first time each file was selected.

appsscript.json:

```
"drive": {
      "onItemsSelectedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onDriveItemsSelected"
      }
```

code.gs:

```
function onDriveItemsSelected(e) {
  console.log(e)
  let card = CardService
    .newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(
      CardService.newCardHeader()
        .setTitle(e.drive.activeCursorItem.title)
    )
  return card.build()
}
```

Adding setStateChanged(true) didn't make a difference, although I'm not sure I was using it correctly:

```
const actionResponse = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNotification(notification)
      .setStateChanged(true);
```